# Import XML file relating parent nodes number to their attributes Power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have the following code to import XML file and convert to table form in Excel 2016 qith Power Query.

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("D:\XML\file.xml")),
    Table0 = Source{0}[Table],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table0,{{"Attribute:index", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Expanded row" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "row", {"column"}, {"row.column"}),
    #"Expanded row.column" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded row", "row.column", {"text"}, {"row.column.text"}),
    #"Expanded row.column.text" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded row.column", "row.column.text", {"Element:Text", "Attribute:fontName", "Attribute:fontSize", "Attribute:x", "Attribute:y", "Attribute:width", "Attribute:height"}, {"row.column.text.Element:Text", "row.column.text.Attribute:fontName", "row.column.text.Attribute:fontSize", "row.column.text.Attribute:x", "row.column.text.Attribute:y", "row.column.text.Attribute:width", "row.column.text.Attribute:height"})
in
    #"Expanded row.column.text"
```

I'm getting almost the output I desire(Index and rest of attributes columns), but I don't know how to add the column for page, row and column corresponding to each attribute.

May someone help me with this please.

This is the output I'm getting with my code.

```
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| index | Text                                     | fontName | fontSize | x      | y      | width  | height |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0     |                                          |          |          |        |        |        |        |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1     | achene –(e.g., strawberry)               | Arial    | 12.0     | 121.10 | 83.42  | 71.04  | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1     | capsule – (e.g., Brazil nut)             | Arial    | 12.0     | 121.10 | 124.82 | 101.07 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1     | caryopsis – (e.g., wheat)                | Arial    | 12.0     | 121.10 | 207.65 | 140.31 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2     | cypsela – (e.g., dandelion)              | Arial    | 12.0     | 85.10  | 69.62  | 24.36  | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 3     |                                          |          |          |        |        |        |        |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | fibrous drupe – (e.g., coconut, walnut)  | Arial    | 12.0     | 276.29 | 239.45 | 95.42  | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | follicle – (e.g., magnolia)              | Arial    | 12.0     | 121.10 | 266.81 | 229.57 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | legume – (e.g., bean, pea, peanut)       | Arial    | 12.0     | 353.94 | 266.81 | 155.71 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | loment – a type of indehiscent legume    | Arial    | 12.0     | 85.10  | 294.41 | 165.10 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | nut – (e.g., beech, hazelnut, oak acorn) | Arial    | 12.0     | 253.43 | 294.41 | 14.39  | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | samara – (e.g., ash, elm, maple key)     | Arial    | 12.0     | 271.04 | 294.41 | 255.64 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4     | schizocarp – (e.g., carrot seed)         | Arial    | 12.0     | 85.10  | 501.43 | 432.97 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 5     | silicle – (e.g., shepherd's purse)       | Arial    | 12.0     | 85.10  | 69.62  | 363.44 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 5     | utricle – (e.g., strawberry)             | Arial    | 12.0     | 85.10  | 83.42  | 382.36 | 12.00  |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 6     |                                          |          |          |        |        |        |        |
+-------+------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

And this is the desired output:

```
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| page | index | row | column | text                                   | fontName | fontSize | x      | y      | width  | height | fontStyle |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 0    | 0     |     |        |                                        |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 1    | 1     | 0   | 0      | achene                                 | Arial    | 12       | 121.1  | 83.42  | 71.04  | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   –(e.g., strawberry)                  |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 1    | 1     | 1   | 0      | capsule                                | Arial    | 12       | 121.1  | 124.82 | 101.07 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., Brazil nut)                 |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 1    | 1     | 2   | 0      | caryopsis                              | Arial    | 12       | 121.1  | 207.65 | 140.31 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., wheat)                      |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 2    | 2     | 0   | 0      | cypsela                                | Arial    | 12       | 85.1   | 69.62  | 24.36  | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., dandelion)                  |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 3    | 3     |     |        |                                        |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 0   | 0      | fibrous                                | Arial    | 12       | 276.29 | 239.45 | 95.42  | 12     | Bold      |
|      |       |     |        |   drupe – (e.g., coconut, walnut)      |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 1   | 1      | follicle                               | Arial    | 12       | 121.1  | 266.81 | 229.57 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., magnolia)                   |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 1   | 1      | legume                                 | Arial    | 12       | 353.94 | 266.81 | 155.71 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., bean, pea, peanut)          |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 2   | 2      | loment                                 | Arial    | 12       | 85.1   | 294.41 | 165.1  | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – a type of indehiscent legume       |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 2   | 2      | nut                                    | Arial    | 12       | 253.43 | 294.41 | 14.39  | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., beech, hazelnut, oak acorn) |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 2   | 2      | samara                                 | Arial    | 12       | 271.04 | 294.41 | 255.64 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., ash, elm, maple key)        |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 4    | 4     | 3   | 0      | schizocarp                             | Arial    | 12       | 85.1   | 501.43 | 432.97 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., carrot seed)                |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 5    | 5     | 0   | 0      | silicle                                | Arial    | 12       | 85.1   | 69.62  | 363.44 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., shepherd's purse)           |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 5    | 5     | 1   | 1      | utricle                                | Arial    | 12       | 85.1   | 83.42  | 382.36 | 12     |           |
|      |       |     |        |   – (e.g., strawberry)                 |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 6    | 6     |     |        |                                        |          |          |        |        |        |        |           |
+------+-------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

This is the input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <page index="0"/>
    <page index="1">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="83.42" width="71.04" height="12.00">achene –(e.g., strawberry)</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="124.82" width="101.07" height="12.00">capsule – (e.g., Brazil nut)</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="207.65" width="140.31" height="12.00">caryopsis – (e.g., wheat)</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="2">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="69.62" width="24.36" height="12.00">cypsela – (e.g., dandelion)</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="3"/>
    <page index="4">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" fontStyle="Bold" x="276.29" y="239.45" width="95.42" height="12.00">fibrous drupe – (e.g., coconut, walnut)</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="121.10" y="266.81" width="229.57" height="12.00">follicle – (e.g., magnolia)</text></column>
             <column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="353.94" y="266.81" width="155.71" height="12.00">legume – (e.g., bean, pea, peanut)</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="294.41" width="165.10" height="12.00">loment – a type of indehiscent legume</text></column>
             <column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="253.43" y="294.41" width="14.39" height="12.00">nut – (e.g., beech, hazelnut, oak acorn)</text></column>
             <column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="271.04" y="294.41" width="255.64" height="12.00">samara – (e.g., ash, elm, maple key)</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="501.43" width="432.97" height="12.00">schizocarp – (e.g., carrot seed)</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="5">
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="69.62" width="363.44" height="12.00">silicle – (e.g., shepherd's purse)</text></column></row>
        <row><column><text fontName="Arial" fontSize="12.0" x="85.10" y="83.42" width="382.36" height="12.00">utricle – (e.g., strawberry)</text></column></row>
    </page>
    <page index="6"/>
</document>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those row and column numbers aren't part of the XML, you'll have to calculate them yourself while you drill down on the levels.

```
let
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("<Path to XML file>")),
    #"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table", {"Attribute:index", "row"}, {"index", "row"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table",{{"index", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Expanded row" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "row", {"column"}, {"column"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded row", "row_index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "row", (C) => if C[column] = null then null else Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [index] = C[index] and [row_index] <= C[row_index]))-1, Int64.Type),
    #"Expanded column" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "column", {"text"}, {"text"}),
    #"Expanded text" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded column", "text", {"Element:Text", "Attribute:fontName", "Attribute:fontSize", "Attribute:x", "Attribute:y", "Attribute:width", "Attribute:height", "Attribute:fontStyle"}, {"Text", "fontName", "fontSize", "x", "y", "width", "height", "fontStyle"}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded text", "col_index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "column", (C) => if C[row] = null then null else Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index1", each [index] = C[index] and [row] = C[row] and [col_index] <= C[col_index]))-1, Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"index", "Text", "fontName", "fontSize", "x", "y", "width", "height", "row", "column", "fontStyle"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{"index", "row", "column", "Text", "fontName", "fontSize", "fontStyle", "x", "y", "width", "height"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"fontName", type text}, {"fontSize", type number}, {"x", type number}, {"y", type number}, {"width", type number}, {"height", type number}, {"Text", type text}, {"fontStyle", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

The tricky bit here is this custom column and the other analogous one:

```
(C) => if C[column] = null then null else
    Table.RowCount(
        Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index",
            each [index] = C[index] and [row_index] <= C[row_index]
        )
    ) - 1
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, thanks for your help. I've been able to try the first code `let ... in .. #"Change Type1"` But where should I insert the second code? `(C) =>...) -1`

Comment: The second code is just an easier to read piece of the `#"Added Custom"` line.

Comment: Ohh ok, Thanks for clarify. I haven't understood hehe, Then t works pretty nice, the only thing I see is the column for fontStyle is not shown in your output.

Comment: I've edited that in. I think it didn't automatically expand that one because it only sampled the first few lines.

Comment: Excellent Alexis. It seems to work pretty nice. I've tried with real file but is about 22MB and is stuck, but I'll wait if finishes. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, the way I've written it is not the most efficient, but it's easier for me to write than a better performing version using e.g. [`List.Accumulate`](https://radacad.com/list-accumulate-hidden-gem-of-power-query-list-functions-in-power-bi).